# Magento custom option text field max length

Tags: magento-1.9

Previously when it was specified, Magento used to honor the max character length for custom input fields, so if I set that to two characters (for initials), it would not let the customer type in more than two characters.

Now I see that even though the note underneath the text field still says maximum two characters allowed, I can type in as many characters as I want. Anyone know how to troubleshoot such problem, I checked my browsers console and see no JavaScript errors being thrown there, any help is welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Default magento not provide character limit while typing in custom option text box so we can use jquey using below code

> $(document).ready(function()
>   {
>       $(".product-options input").attr('maxlength','3');
>   });

you need set character limit. Replace 3 with your character limit number.

i hope it will be helpful for you !!

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, but that will not work for us because we have more than one textfield and only one needs to have a size restriction.

Comment: Ok then you can use input position if its first then use `input:first-child` if other then use `input:nth-child(n)` if its last then use `input:last-child` . Just replace input with input and its position.

Comment: I had to make some changes to this suggestion to make it work, because when I used input:first-child or :nth-child it was setting restrictions either to all textfields or not setting them at all. I used input:eq(n) instead and that let me select second value and only add character restrictions on that variable.

Comment: This is your answer `jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
jQuery(".input-box input:eq(1)").attr('maxlength','3')
});`  its working for second input box @K.I